# Choosing GeoCoding service?

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, web-service, reverse-geocoding

I'm looking for a web service providing a full address based on coordinates (and reverse).

I'm ready to pay for that service.

I don't want to use Google's API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via Michelin (best for Europe)

SOAP
http://dev.viamichelin.com/web/api-soap/documentation?WSDoc=GeoV3

REST
http://dev.viamichelin.com/web/api-rest/documentation/1.0/geocoding

Mapquest Open API (based on OpenStreeMap data)
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/geocoding-ws

Microsoft Geocoding
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx

Geonames
http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend deCarta. We powered google maps, yahoo maps and a ton of other people. We just announced new pricing. We expose our geocoding (and reverse geocoding) through many different apis. We also have worldwide coverage.

http://developer.decarta.com

We actually have other emergency systems running on our platform.

Note that deCarta was acquired by Uber][1](http://mashable.com/2015/03/03/uber-acquires-mapping-decarta/#Vo8Gw3_CaGq0) and their API is no longer available.

**Disclaimer**: I work for deCarta.

Comment: The problem with DeCarta is, that you are not allowed to store the results in your database (Source: Email from February 2013)

Comment: I don't know of any COMMERCIAL service that will let you do that. All of the charge by transaction and storing the values would basically undercut their revenue model

Comment: If you have objects you want to display on a map, it doesn't make any sence to ALWAYS query the geocoding service. Especially if they do not change. 
We are using [Geocodefarm](https://geocodefarm.com). They let you do this.

Comment: It seems that the above link is no longer valid, and people should head to http://developer.tomtom.com (_Following the Uber acquisition of deCarta ...our DevZone will no longer be open_)

Comment: Put in an update - thanks for reminding me of this response

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you try out Geocode.Farm (https://geocode.farm). You can always just past the address into the address bar the same as you would put it into a form and it will display in XML the output, but it is human readable:

000.00000
-000.000000

Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: GeocodeFarm now [offers reverse geocoding](http://www.geocodefarm.com/web-service/reverse/)

Comment: They have very confusing terms of services though. https://geocodefarm.com/policies/terms-of-service/

Comment: I just want to second GeocodeFarm.  They have provided the most accurate locations for me (not including services like Bing or Google where you're forced to use their mapping products). If anybody is on the fence, definitely give them a try

Comment: At this point (year 2020) I would not recommend geocode.farm. 1) They do not work consitently. Running same query against their API can return no results and it can return results. 2) At this point they sometimes return statuses that their own documentation does not have. 3) They just do not work occasionally. Do not recommend them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PickPoint](https://pickpoint.io/). 
That's a pretty expeditious service providing geocoding as well as reverse geocoding by attractive price.

You can even choose Free plan if the number of requests is below 2500 per day.

Comment: PickPoint is great. Good pricing, and good results.

Answer (score 2):

*Posting a new answer here as this ranks highly on Google on the topic of Geocoder result licensing.*

Here's what I understand to be true for the non-enterprise version of Google Maps / Google Places:

1. You can't store geospatial data or address data
2. You can store some data, but only for performance purposes in limited cases (see https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5)
3. You can store the Place ID indefinitely (see https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id)

   > Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 10.5.d of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely.

Based on my own recollection, Google Maps TOS has improved quite a bit, and they do clarify what you can and cannot do a little better now.

Comment: I just want to clarify one point on storing data from google maps. From the TOS: "You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service." it says this in differing ways in at least three parts of the TOS. In other words. you can store the geocodes, but only if you are going to be using them on a Google Maps/Earth application.

Comment: @BradMathews this is an interesting observation; I hope it isn't a knot of definitions (such as what exactly "Service" is). Would you mind sharing your notes on this regarding the differences found in the locations of the TOS?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for international geocoding and checked out decarta and viamichelin. I couldn't make heads or tails of the viamichelin site so I moved on to decarta. I downloaded their api and was geocoding addy's in Denmark in no time. Their prices are the best I've found on the web. I called them for some more information and the CEO of the company called back was extremely helpful.

Go with DeCarta - first 1,000,000 geocodes are free, $2.80/1000 after that.

Answer (score 0):

For Europe try [Geocode.XYZ](http://geocode.xyz)

It is free. (based on openstreetmap and openaddresses.io ) Does Geocoding (forward and reverse) batch geocoding and geoparsing from text for over 50 European countries.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".